# Responsive JavaFX BorderPane

Tags: javafx

I am programming a Music Player with JavaFX and Scene Builder.
My problem is, that if I resize the Window of my program, the UI does not grow with it. How to make the UI responsive?

Before I added the SplashScreen, it worked fine.
Since then I tried to get it to work, but I can't find any solution on the web!

Please help me, thanks in advance!

[image: Screenshot without resizing]

[image: Screenshot resized]

Main:

```
    package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static boolean isSplashLoaded = false;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Juggle v0.1");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1024, 640));
        primaryStage.setResizable(true);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
    package sample;

import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class Controller implements Initializable{


    public MenuItem openFile;
    public BorderPane parent;

    public void openFile(){
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setTitle("Open File...");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Audio Files", "*.wav", "*.mp3"));
        File f = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(parent.getScene().getWindow());

        if ( f != null) {

            Media pick = new Media(f.toURI().toString());
            MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(pick);
            MediaView view = new MediaView(player);
            parent.getChildren().add(view);
            player.play();
        }
        else{

        }

    }



    public void loadSplashScreen() throws IOException {
        Main.isSplashLoaded = true;
        BorderPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Splash.fxml"));
        parent.getChildren().setAll(pane);

        FadeTransition fadeIn = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(3), pane);
        fadeIn.setFromValue(0);
        fadeIn.setToValue(1);
        fadeIn.setCycleCount(1);

        FadeTransition fadeOut = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(3), pane);
        fadeOut.setFromValue(1);
        fadeOut.setToValue(0);
        fadeOut.setCycleCount(1);

        fadeIn.play();

        fadeIn.setOnFinished((e) ->{
            fadeOut.play();
        });

        fadeOut.setOnFinished((e) -> {
            try {
                BorderPane parentContent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
                parent.getChildren().setAll(parentContent);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
            if(!Main.isSplashLoaded){
                try {
                    if(!Main.isSplashLoaded){
                        loadSplashScreen();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

    }
}
```

FXML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<BorderPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" fx:id="parent"
    maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"
    minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="640.0" prefWidth="1024.0"
    style="-fx-background-color: #93F979;"
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <bottom>
      <BorderPane prefHeight="93.0" prefWidth="600.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <top>
            <HBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="800.0" BorderPane.alignment="TOP_CENTER">
               <children>
                  <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="50.0" text="00:00" textAlignment="CENTER" />
                  <ProgressBar prefHeight="10.0" prefWidth="900.0" progress="0.0">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets top="4.0" />
                     </HBox.margin></ProgressBar>
                  <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="50.0" text="00:00" textAlignment="CENTER" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </top>
      </BorderPane>
    </bottom>
    <center>
      <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true"
         BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../Music.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
   </center>
   <top>
      <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem fx:id="openFile" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openFile" text="Open..." />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
    </top>
</BorderPane>
```

Splash FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane fx:id="BorderPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="640.0" prefWidth="1024.0" style="-fx-background-color: #93F979;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Main">
   <center>
      <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" nodeOrientation="INHERIT" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../Splash.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use static methods of BorderPane class like this

```
BorderPane.setAlignment ( node , Pos.CENTER );
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using VBox instead?

Comment: I am using different Panes in Scene Builder, but the main one is a BorderPane.
Do i have to use VBox as the main one to get it done?
Then my question is, do i have to use VBox on SplashScreen or on the main Screen?
Because only with VBox i cant get the layout design done

Comment: I would suggest trying to replace it with a VBox. It should work pefect for your situation. Otherwise you could also try to use AnchorPane and make use of the AnchorPane constraints.

Comment: If i start from scratch again, is it possible to start with VBox and place a BorderPane at the same size right inside of it? Because i need the layout for things like playlists later on.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that.